# Convert JSON to GeoDataFrame and append both geometry and filename

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, json, geodataframe

I am currently running an experiment on automating a task by merging information from various file types and doing a number of operations to achieve this.

Currently, I am reading a list of GeoJSONs and trying to build a GeoDataFrame that contains both the geometry and the filename.

Example of file name structure in folder is: event1.json

The desired geodataframe should look like this:

```
    index     geometry                      event_name
    0         LINESTRING1(coordinates...)   event1
    1         LINESTRING2(coordinates...)   event2
    2         LINESTRING3(coordinates...)   event3
```

I am able to read the JSONs and create the geometries, but I am not able to assign the matching filename.

```
     import os, geopandas as gpd

     event_tracks = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['geometry', 'eventname'])

     directory = os.getcwd()

     
     for dir_root, dir_dir, js_file  in os.walk(directory):
       for f in js_file:
         if f.endswith(".json"):
         fname = os.path.basename(f)
         fname, fext = fname.split('.')
         print (fname)
         print ('Reading Track Path JSON ' + f)
         with open(f, 'r') as path_f:
           event_tracks = gpd.read_file(path_f).append(event_tracks)
```

The code above works for geometries and generates a geodataframe with valid geometries.
However, I cannot assign the event name into the column. So far, I've tried to:

- Create list of names and append list elements
- Reindex and concatenate two different dataframes

However, it either returns a NaN-filled column or an error such as: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid.

Is there any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the event name is equals the file name, you would need to assign the event name to each newly "imported" dataframe **before** appending.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd

event_tracks = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    columns=["geometry", "eventname"],
    geometry="geometry",
    crs="EPSG:4326"  # replace with correct CRS
)

search_path = os.getcwd()

for path in Path(search_path).glob("**/*.json"):
    
    print(f"Reading Track Path JSON {path.name}")

    tracks = gpd.read_file(path.absolute())
    tracks["eventname"] = path.stem  # file name
    
    event_tracks = tracks.append(event_tracks)
```

**Some other notes:**

- There is no need to open the file since [`gpd.read_file(...)`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html) also accepts a file path.
- Don't forget to define the geometry column and the CRS.
- [`for path in Path(search_path).glob("**/*.json")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a more concise way to iterate through all JSON files within the current and sub directories. It makes the code more readable but requires at least Python 3.5.
- The example above uses a [f-String](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) which was introduced with Python 3.6.

---

However, if your Python version is older than 3.5. Here an example using `os.walk(...)` (and without using a f-string):

```py
import os
import geopandas as gpd

event_tracks = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    columns=["geometry", "eventname"],
    geometry="geometry",
    crs="EPSG:4326"  # replace with correct CRS
)

search_path = os.getcwd()

for root_path, _, file_names in os.walk(search_path):
    
    for file_name in file_names:
        
        if file_name.endswith(".json"):

            print("Reading Track Path JSON " + file_name)
    
            file_path = os.path.join(root_path, file_name)

            tracks = gpd.read_file(file_path)
            
            event_name = file_name.split(".")[0]
            tracks["eventname"] = event_name
            
            event_tracks = tracks.append(event_tracks)
```

Comment: Thank you! I only got to look at it today, but it worked. I guess when you spend to much time on it, you fail to see the issue. For clarity, I used the first solution, for my version of Python 3.7.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I was able to help you. If my answer solved your question, please select it as accepted answer.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I thought I ticked that mark.